# ChatFx Lite LicenseException on build server

Tags: chartfx

I downloaded ChartFx Lite and am using it successfully in my windows forms application on my development machine.  I have added the ChartFX.Lite.dll assembly to my source repository and am trying to build the project on my build server that does not have ChartFx Lite installed.  I get the error:

> Exception occurred creating type 'SoftwareFX.ChartFX.Lite.Chart, ChartFX.Lite, Version=6.0.839.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=a1878e2052c08dce' System.ComponentModel.LicenseException: Couldn't get Design Time license for 'SoftwareFX.ChartFX.Lite.Chart'

What do I need to do to get this working without installing ChartFx Lite on my build server?

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to test the build, you can suppress the lines concerning ChartFx from the .licx file created by Visual Studio. It should build this way, but probably will not execute correctly, as the license will not be included.

The .licx file contains instructions to include binary license resource during build. I'm afraid that if you want a real build you have to install ChartFx on the build server.